# Show videos only in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using following code to present UIImagePickerController.For some particular scenario I want only videos.And using the following code.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
imagePickerController.allowsEditing=NO;

imagePickerController.mediaTypes=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,nil];

[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But it showing Camera Roll,My Photo Stream and Videos in a tableview.If I open any folder the contents are only videos.I want Only Videos how can I achieve this.Also the title Photos,I want to change that also toVideos.

Answer (score 12):

Swift 3 update :

```
let videoPicker = UIImagePickerController()  
videoPicker.delegate = self
videoPicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
videoPicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
self.present(videoPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Import **import MobileCoreServices** and add delegates **UIImagePickerControllerDelegate** and **UINavigationControllerDelegate** in the top

The presented modal will have "Photos" title.
You can change it like this :

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        viewController.navigationItem.title = "Choose Video"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
```

and

```
[controller setMediaTypes:@[(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get all the videos collection(from camera roll, photo library) in a single shot, you do need to navigate to and from "Camera roll", "Photo Library" to choose the desired video.

You can choose source type to any of the following enum

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIImagePickerControllerSourceType) {
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary,
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera,
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum
};
```

and set the desired media types.